# Travel without residence permit in schengen zone

Tags: schengen, residency, identity-cards, turkish-citizens, lost-documents

I live in Poland. I am a citizen of Turkey, so I am a non-EU citizen. Few days ago i lost my residence card and in 7-8 days i will go to Italy for a nice trip.

I know it's a domestic flight from Poland to Italy, however someone told me that some flight companies are checking validity of your documents. I have a ticket from RyanAir. How screwed up am I?

Comment: This is right. The risk is limited but they might check. Hard to give you a risk assessment. Maybe ask for another residence card.

Comment: My (albeit limited) experience shows that if you are not flying home or to your country of residence, you might not be allowed on the flight. On the other hand, a traveller who loses their residency card whilst abroad is usually allowed to fly home, given a police statement and as much complementary information as possible to prove that they are indeed allowed to stay in the Schengen area. Personally I'd try to get a new residency card asap.

Comment: Many airlines don't check, but Ryanair is unfortunately not one of them.